# PHP Curl and setcookie problem

Tags: php, cookies, curl, setcookie

I have a curl script that acts as proxy between client and main server.

......

```
$field_array= array(
      'Accept' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT',
      'Accept-Charset' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET',
      'Accept-Encoding' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING',
      'Accept-Language' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE',
      'Connection' => 'HTTP_CONNECTION',
      'Host' => 'HTTP_HOST',
      'Referer' => 'HTTP_REFERER',
      'User-Agent' => 'HTTP_USER_AGENT'
      );

$curl_request_headers=array();

foreach ($field_array as $key => $value) {
   if(isset($_SERVER["$value"])) {
      $server_value=$_SERVER["$value"];
      $curl_request_headers[]="$key: $server_value";
   }
};
$curl_request_headers[]="Expect: ";

session_write_close();


//Open connection
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_COOKIE,session_name()."=".session_id().";");
//Set the url, POST data
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, !empty($user_post_data));
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $user_post_data);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_request_headers);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);
//Close connection
curl_close($curl_handle);
list($headers,$content)=explode("\r\n\r\n",$result,2);
foreach (explode("\r\n",$headers) as $hdr) {
   if(preg_match("/Transfer-Encoding:.*chunked/i", $hdr)) {
      // Remove chunked headers. Not properly handled by browsers
   } else {
      header($hdr);
   };
}
echo $content;
```

Now, on main server, I set a cookie in an script and then try to read its value in another script. I cannot read the value. So there is some problem passing the value around in curl. How to fix?

thanks

### FOUND SOLUTION:

Actually, a stupid problem. I need to explicitly set cookies in CURLOPT_COOKIE. Following code now works  for me:

```
......
$_COOKIE[session_name()]=session_id();

$cookie_string="";
foreach( $_COOKIE as $key => $value ) {
  $cookie_string .= "$key=$value;";
};

//Open connection
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie_string);
......
```

Comment: I think you should use the COOKIEJAR and COOKIEFILE functions.

Comment: It's okay to answer your own question as an answer, instead of in the question

Comment: @Jon: Thanks... it wasnt allowing me to answer for next 8 hours...

Comment: now you could post your answer and accept it

Answer (score 10):

you have to add space after semicolon so the best way is:

```
$cookie = array();
foreach( $_COOKIE as $key => $value ) {
  $cookie[] = "{$key}={$value}";
};

$cookie = implode('; ', $cookie);

$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
```

Comment: +1 - I had to `rawurlencode()` the value because some of my values had semicolons.  `$cookie[] = $key ."=". rawurlencode($value);`

Comment: Consider use `http_build_query($cookies, null, ';')` instead of foreach.

Answer (score 9):

Consider [http_build_cookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-cookie.php) instead of imploding cookies string or, if you have no pecl_http installed just:

```
http_build_query($cookies, null, ';')
```

Pretty simple.