# setting a cookie in PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, cookies

Im really new to the php curl concept, can anybody show me a simple example of how to set a cookie in the browser using **php curl**

this is my code that doesnt work...

```
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/setc.php?userid=123&panelid=1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// get headers too with this line
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

but when i take a var_dump of this it gets printed, very confused please help

```
array (size=1)
  'userid' => string '1:123' (length=8)
```

**please if ur confused....u can simply ignore my above coding and let me know how to set a simple cookie using php curl**

Answer (score 21):

I'm not clear on what you are expecting to have happen with cookies.  However, you might try this:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/setc.php?userid=123&panelid=1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// get headers too with this line
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'cookiename=cookievalue');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: what i meant is i cant create a simple cookie using CURL,, so i seeked help from u guys

Comment: I added the setopt for adding a cookie

Comment: seems like php curl not working with cookies anymore after 2016, not sure

Comment: The cookie jar requires an absolute path to the cookie file.  You might want to try `realpath($cookie_jar_path)`

Answer (score 6):

Php Curl allows you to directly set the cookie Header, using:

```
curl_setopt($curlHandle,CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookieString);
```

Where *$cookieStrin*g holds semicolon separated key=value pairs of cookie data.

Please refer to this question:
[PHP Curl and setcookie problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453347/php-curl-and-setcookie-problem)

And be sure to thoroughly go through http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: thanks i understand $cookiestring.. can u please tell me what does $curlHandle,CURLOPT_COOKIE holds

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
```

This will automatically create one cookies.txt